# How to properly backup OS X Server (Mavericks)

Tags: time-machine, backup, osx-server

I've been reading various articles from a Google Search on this topic and it seems there is no clear solution as many debate what works/doesn't work. I'm hoping to get a definitive answer here.

I have a Mac Mini running 10.9.2 with Server App installed. I run the following services on it: Caching, DHCP, DNS, File Sharing, Open Directory, Profile Manager, Software Updates, Time Machine, Websites, VPN, and Xcode.

I'd like to use Time Machine, but read it won't backup Open Directory. Carbon Copy also states it will not backup OD. I'd like to be able to restore my entire system from a disk image if possible if something were to go wrong.

What solution(s) do any of you OS X Sys Admins perform to accomplish this? Also, is there a way to automate creating an archive of Open Directory?

Answer (score 1):

I use Carbon Copy Cloner (actually Super Duper - but same idea) to back up my system drive to another drive.

Additionally, I have another CPU which acts as an Open Directory Replica in case the first one goes down.
(granted, this means you need 2 CPUs - so it's not the cheapest solution!)

You can find some more info about OD Replica here:
http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/12/a-power-users-guide-to-os-x-server-mavericks-edition/2/